# Ошибка при компиляции в Xcode - (SocketIO) после серии багфиксов

Tags: xcode, swift

Изначально была следующая строка кода:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Потом следующая:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И потом следующая:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После серии багфиксов услужливо предложенных средой разработки выдает ошибку при компиляции: 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите пожалуйста, понимаю, что вопрос нубский, однако что должно быть прописано после "nsp" вместо <#String#> в строке кода:

```
var socket : SocketIOClient = SocketIOClient(manager: URL(string: BASE_URL)! as! SocketManagerSpec, nsp: <#String#> )
```

С радостью отвечу на все необходимые вопросы!
Вот весь код файла(если нужно конечно):

```
import UIKit
import SocketIO

class SocketService: NSObject {

    static let instance = SocketService()

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    var socket : SocketIOClient = SocketIOClient(manager: URL(string: BASE_URL)! as! SocketManagerSpec, nsp:<#String#>)

    func establishConnection() {
        socket.connect()
    }

    func closeConnection(){
        socket.disconnect()
    }

    func addChannel(channelName: String, channelDescription: String, completion: @escaping CompletionHandler) {
         socket.emit("newChannel", channelName, channelDescription)
         completion(true)
    }

    func getChannel(completion: @escaping CompletionHandler) {
        socket.on("channelCreated") { (dataArray, ack) in
            guard let channelName = dataArray[0] as? String else { return }
            guard let channelDesc = dataArray[1] as? String else { return }
            guard let channelId = dataArray[2] as? String else { return }

            let newChannel = Channel(channelTitle: channelName, channelDescription: channelDesc, id: channelId)
            MessageService.instance.channels.append(newChannel)
            completion(true)
        }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам же Xcode говрит что там нужно строку вписать а у вас плейсхолдер, а в менеджер передется клас который отвечает протоколу SocketManagerSpec

Читайте [документацию](https://nuclearace.github.io/Socket.IO-Client-Swift/Classes/SocketIOClient.html#/c:@M@SocketIO@objc(cs)SocketIOClient(im)initWithManager:nsp:)

```
var myManager = MyManagerClass()
var socket : SocketIOClient = SocketIOClient(manager: myManager, nsp: "The url of the socket.io server." )
```

ну и там какой-то менеджер

```
class MyManagerClass: SocketManagerSpec {
     //реализация протокола SocketManagerSpec
     //...
}
```

Comment: Cпасибо вам за ответ! Это мне помогло. И да, я понимал, что строку нужно вписать,  понимал, что это плейсхолдер, но какую именно строку было нужно вписать? Пробовал вбивать рендомную строку - ошибка оставалась! Сейчас вроде бы все нормально, компилятор не ругается! Еще раз спасибо!